# How do you close 1 window of a gui that has 2 windows open without closing both?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Wondering how to close a window of a gui without closing out of the whole thing.

Comment: Very short question... I think you're forgetting to include something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a Swing question, then the main GUI window should be a JFrame and the dependent or dialog window should be a JDialog, not a JFrame.

---

**Edit**
You ask in comment:

> what if it is a jframe...

My reply:
that's just it. It ***shouldn't*** be a JFrame. Period. Please note that a JDialog can hold and display anything that a JFrame does.

Comment: what if it is a jframe...

Comment: @user3184504: see edit to answer.

Comment: can you still do all the things you can with a jframe then with a jdialog @Hovercraft full of eels

Comment: @user3184504: see edit to answer.

Comment: Really? What about a `JFrame` with a default close operation of `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`? What if you invoke `JFrame#dispose()`?

Comment: @JoshM: true, there is that behavioral difference, but that's just it -- using a JDialog changes the window's closing behavior so that it doesn't close down the entire GUI, ***which is his goal and the entire reason for this question***.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you use a Swing GUI in Java.)

There is a [`setDefaultCloseOperation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29) method of `JFrame` class. It allows you to control whether to close the whole application or only dispose window when it is closed.

Comment: No, then closing the main JFrame won't behave as expected. The better solution is to use a JDialog as the dependent window.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: How do you know there's a main window? Some apps can use multiple "main" windows. And even in the asymmetric case, the main frame can be `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` and the others just `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`. Before you say that a dialog is meant for this... I could say a dialog is meant to be modal (which might or mightn't fit).